# Configuring docker virtual repository in artifactory

Tags: nginx, docker, virtual, artifactory

I have a local docker repository and a remote docker repository , I created a virtual docker repository combining both. In order to access this repository from the client side, does this need to be added to the reverse proxy as well?

Here is the current reverse proxy configuration

```
 upstream artifactory_lb {

        server myserver.mycompany.com:8081 backup;
        server myserver.mycompany.com:8081;
}


log_format upstreamlog '[$time_local] $remote_addr - $remote_user - $server_name  to: $upstream_addr: $request upstream_response_time $upstream_response_time msec $msec request_time $request_time';
ssl_certificate  /etc/nginx/ssl/multidomain_cert_files/mycert.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/multidomain_cert_files/mykey.key;
ssl_protocols TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128:AES256:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4';
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;

server {
        listen 80;
        listen 443  ssl;
        client_max_body_size 2048M;
        location / {
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_pass http://artifactory_lb;
                proxy_read_timeout 90;
        }
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log upstreamlog;
        location /basic_status {
                stub_status on;
                allow all;
                }
}

# Server configuration

server {
    listen 2222 ssl;

    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = '') {
        set $http_x_forwarded_proto  $scheme;
    }

    rewrite ^/(v1|v2)/(.*) /api/docker/myrepo_images/$1/$2;
    client_max_body_size 0;
    chunked_transfer_encoding on;

    location / {
    allow all;s
    proxy_read_timeout  900;
    proxy_pass_header   Server;
    proxy_cookie_path ~*^/.* /;
    proxy_set_header   X-Artifactory-Override-Base-Url $http_x_forwarded_proto://$host:$server_port;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Port  $server_port;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto $http_x_forwarded_proto;
    proxy_set_header    Host              $http_host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass http://artifactory_lb/artifactory/;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**. Docker registries are referenced by their host name, only. This means that you'll need two virtual hosts in your reverse proxy with different hostnames (use the [`server_name` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) for that), mapping to different Artifactory repositories.

The following example config (shortened) should do the trick:

```
server {
    listen 2222 ssl;
    server_name local-repo.my-artifactory.com;

    rewrite ^/(v1|v2)/(.*) /api/docker/myrepo_images/$1/$2;

    # <insert remaining configuration directives here>
}

server {
    listen 2222 ssl;
    server_name virtual-repo.my-artifactory.com;

    rewrite ^/(v1|v2)/(.*) /api/docker/myrepo_virtual/$1/$2;

    # <insert remaining configuration directives here>
}
```

Now you should be able to access both registries using the regular docker commands:

```
$ docker pull virtual-repo.my-artifactory.com:2222/foo/bar:latest
$ docker pull local-repo.my-artifactory.com:2222/foo/bar:latest
$ docker push local-repo.my-artifactory.com:2222/foo/bar:latest
```

Comment: Thanks helmbert, in order to mitigate the changes on the client side, can the two repositories be configured with the same server name but on different ports?

Comment: @user_mda, sure; just adjust the `listen` directives in the virtual hosts to whatever ports you like.

Comment: @user_mda  You should learn to accept good answers - like this one. You have only accepted *one* answer to any ofl your questions.